# SEO on ui-router states of AngularJS SPA

Tags: seo, google, javascript, googlebot

I have a simple SPA created with AngularJS, you can see it running here: [www.consami.com.br](http://consami.com.br). I was using [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) to load a pure HTML version for crawlers, however some pages were not indexed by Googlebot. So searching again about how make my page indexed correctly, I discovered that [Ajax Crawling was deprecated](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.br/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) and decided remove the prerender processing of this application, so google could catch my page like it is. However, the same way it was before, google just crawled my root page. As I saw [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459723/is-angular-js-with-ui-router-seo-friendly#answer-25178952) I changed the links of my main page from

```
ui-sref="descricao"
```

to

```
ng-href="descricao"
```

I know that javascript pages are not correctly indexed by search bots, however, as google says it can process javascript pages like if a person is accessing, I believe it should index my page correctly. What could I do to make my states (pages like [this](http://consami.com.br/descricao)) indexed?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: This is how your website appears in Google's view. Google can't read javaScript content. To verify this use fetch and render option available in Google search console]
This is how your website appears in Google's view. Google can't read javaScript content. To verify this use fetch and render option available in Google search console

Check out this more:

[AngularJS application and searchengine optimization, empty Google cached page version](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/111716/angularjs-application-and-searchengine-optimization-empty-google-cached-page-ve/117036#117036)