# AngularJS application and searchengine optimization, empty Google cached page version

Tags: seo, angular.js

I have created a website using AngularJS. I'm not sure this website will be properly indexed by Google and other search engines.

The cached Google versions of the indexed pages are white with no content.

Please advise - is it a normal behavior because of a very young website or I should use solutions like `https://prerender.io` in order to improve the visibility in SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want to find/build a backend rendering tool for your initial view. If you view source on those pages, you won't find any meaningful content for the bots to scan. The robots aren't rendering a page, so 90% of what matters is the text content of the HTML file the robot loads.

You'll at the very least want your description and reviews to load (reviews because of freshness and diversity of content). You don't need something complex like prerender. If you have trouble, you can dynamically backend populate the description/reviews in the ui-view without even running angular on the backend. Angular will delete everything in the ui-view on render and replace it with the page, but that's okay as long as you're replacing it with the same content.

Answer (score 0):

For angular apps SEO is quite different. Check Deliver search-friendly JavaScript-powered websites (Google I/O '18)

Google can't render JavaScript. For Angular applications consider hybrid rendering like Angular Universal.

Use fetch and render option in search console which might shows white blank pages for Angular applications. Also check with Google mobile friendliness test.